# How do I get Applications tile?

Tags: docusignapi

At the following [page](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent#admin-consent-for-external-applications) they say:

> From the organization dashboard, click the Applications tile.

I am using sandbox and do not see any "Applications tile". [Here is what I see.](https://prnt.sc/rurolq)
Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grant consent for internal apps, you will have to first create a DocuSign organization. You can do this by selecting the "Get Started" button in your screenshot.

Once your org is created, you can access it easily by selecting the dropdown in the upper right, then choosing "Admin."

In the Organization Admin view, you should select the "Connected Apps" tile from the options, choose the app you would like to grant access, and set the appropriate permissions. (likely `signature impersonation`)

Let me know if that works for you!